# Download a file from S3 Bucket using boto3 by passing credentials as parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3

As per Boto3 official documentation, we can connect S3 bucket by passing credentials as a parameters. But I am facing issues.

**Working Scenario : Hardcoding Key ID & Secret Key**

```
s3r = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
buck = s3r.Bucket('bucket name')
buck.download_file(filename,filename)
```

**Non Working Scenario : Passing as parameters**

```
AccessKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
SecretKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
s3r = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=AccessKey, aws_secret_access_key=SecretKey)
buck = s3r.Bucket('bucket name')
buck.download_file(filename,filename)
```

I am facing below error for non-working scenario.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Comment: do you access to the same bucket and object? what is policy of your bucket?

Comment: @cuongnv yes, i do have access to the bucket. If you see above, I am using same credentials & trying to access same bucket in both scenarios. Hard coding the credentials works but passing it as parameter not working. Any idea?

Comment: Your exception means that your accounr doesn't have permission to do a HeadObject to bucket. See here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html. That's why I asked about your policy

Answer (score 2):

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html

```
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=AccessKey, aws_secret_access_key=SecretKey)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
```

Comment: This is how i am downloading file now but any idea why is it not working when passing it as parameter but works when hardcoded?